# Image as a border around a box

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to get a border like the picture below:

[image]

But instead of dots, I want to use a picture of a car with the background cut out.
A little line of cars all the way around the box.
How can I do that?

Here's my attempt:

```css
.box-head {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00e6ff, #6418ff);
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Skyline's Pointless Website</title>
  <link rel="border" href"border.png">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-head">
    <h1>Welcome fello plebs to this completely pointless website.</h1>
    <p> You may notice this website isn't that good. I just started learning html and css so leave me alone.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the car image:
[image: Car]

Comment: Please use the tools provided to give us the pastebin code in the post.

Comment: You might find [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) useful.

Comment: there's a typo on the `link`: correct: `href="border.png"`. But you don't need this, follow the link above.

Comment: So do i need to have the code for the border outside of .box-head? I've been trying all kinds of border image commands and nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image):

> The border-image CSS property lets you draw an image in place of an element's border-style.

```css
.box-head {
  padding: 42px;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  border-image-source: url("//mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6017/border-image-6.svg");
  border-image-slice: 42 fill;
  border-image-width: 42px;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-head">
  <h1>Welcome fello plebs to this completely pointless website.</h1>
  <p> You may notice this website isn't that good. I just started learning html and css so leave me alone.</p>
</div>
```

Using an online generator might help demonstrate how it works:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator)
[border-image.com](http://border-image.com/)

Also see:
[css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)
[bitsofco.de](https://bitsofco.de/understanding-border-image/)
[thenewcode.com](http://thenewcode.com/438/CSS-Border-Image-Explained)

---

### Edit

You explained that you want a line of cars around the box.

To do this with `border-image`, make an image with the car tiled in a 3x3 grid. The different "zones" are described in documentation for [`border-image-slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice):

[image: 3x3 sliced grid]

> - Zones 1-4 are corner regions. Each one is used a single time to form the corners of the final border image.
> - Zones 5-8 are edge regions. These are repeated, scaled, or otherwise modified in the final border image to match the dimensions of the element.
> - Zone 9 is the middle region. It is discarded by default, but is used like a background image if the keyword fill is set.

Here's my example image:

[image: 3x3 Car Grid]

Here's a working example of the border:

```css
.box-head {
  padding: 30px 100px;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image-source: url("//i.stack.imgur.com/ODGdz.png");
  border-image-slice: 30 100;
  border-image-width: 30px 100px;
  border-image-outset: 0;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-head">
  <h1>Welcome fello plebs to this completely pointless website.</h1>
  <p> You may notice this website isn't that good. I just started learning html and css so leave me alone.</p>
</div>
```

For more reference on this method, see:
[Making a Border of a Single Repeating Image](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/#article-header-id-10)
[Border Imaging](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/24/border-imaging/)

---

### EDIT

Here's an example with the cars rotated:

[image: Rotated Car Grid]

```css
.box-head {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image-source: url("//i.stack.imgur.com/YQ4EO.png");
  border-image-slice: 30 100;
  border-image-width: 30px 100px;
  border-image-outset: 0;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-head">
  <h1>Welcome, humans, to this amazing website.</h1>
  <p> You may notice this website tickles your brain. I just started learning HTML and CSS, so the universe is wide open!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So it's sort of working, it looks really weird and there's opposite colors on the ends of the box. http://prntscr.com/is6klo

Comment: It might help if you can provide the actual image you're using.

Comment: Yeah sorry, here it is. I'm still trying to figure out this website. -.- https://prntscr.com/is6obu

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I misunderstood your question. That image doesn't seem particularly appropriate for a border. How do you intend it to look?

Comment: To make it sit around the box like this and all line up, with the box further down in the page so there's more space in the top http://prntscr.com/is6txu

Comment: But the car isn't shaped like a border. Will it be a line of little cars all the way around the box? Or the car with a a box in the middle?

Comment: A little line of cars all the way around the box. I don't know if that's really possible but if not i'll end up doing something else that i have an idea for.

Comment: For that purpose, `border-image` will require a special image: a 3x3 grid. Please see my edit.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try messing around with it, might not end up doing it but i'll try, could i get the ones on the left and right side of the border to be sideways? 
Edit: it just makes a black border around it, no cars.

Comment: Yes, you can edit the image grid however you see fit (see edit). About the black border, maybe you still have `border: 5px;` in your code. Can you show me what you've got?